# amount (share) folder in Unix-AIX by using smitty?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, aix, network-share

how i can amount folder in unix-aix by using `smitty` command ???

Comment: Do you mean, how can you find the space used by a folder by using smitty?

Comment: yes Ben ........

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the capacity of a filesystem, you can go to:
Smit ->  System Storage Management -> File Systems -> Add / Change / Show / Delete File Systems -> Enhanced Journaled File Systems (Or whichever you run ) -> Change / Show Characteristics of an Enhanced Journaled File System -> Select Filesystem

Through this you can view the number of units for the capacity of a filesystem

To find the space used in a folder I'm not sure why you would want to go through Smit, but I don't believe there is a way.

[This site](http://icancompute.ca/aix/aix-commands/aix-command-du-disk-usage/) goes into detail on how to investigate disk usage however, might be helpful.